# How can I validate date with or without month and days at same time in Yii?

Tags: validation, date, yii

How can I validate date with or without month and days at same time in Yii?
I mean can I validate date like year only(2011) or whole(2011-01-02) at same time in Yii ??

Comment: so you want to validate only year from any date time format, right ? what exactly do you want to validate in year, I mean if the year is greater than current year or ... ??

Comment: I want to validate date format like 2011-01-02(yyyy-mm-dd) or only 2011(yyyy) in my input field. That's it. How can i do that?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CTypeValidator

Comment: show what you tried?

Comment: @Insane I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: you can use php function for it `date("Y")` and `date("Y-m-d")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just validate years then just add this in model rules like this.

```
return array(
   array('your-date-attribute','your_function')
);
```

And add the below function on that model.

```
public function your_function($attribute,$params)
    {
        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$this->your-date-attribute) && !preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}$/",$this->your-date-attribute))
        {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Date is not valid date!');
        }
    }
```